# Pebble -> Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

I've started developing a PebbelLib for WP8 (app will follow as well). I'm running in some issues, and I dont know where the bug is. Maybe anybody here can help me?

The code can be find on git (https://github.com/p3root/P3bble).

My Issue:
I dont get answers from the pebble (except the first 2 times). A bug from me, a bug in pebble?! My pebble runs on version 1.11.1. HW Rev is V2R2.

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks
p3root

Comment: You're not going to beat me to make a WP8 pebble app! :P (there's already a lib: https://github.com/barometz/flint)

Comment: You're lib only works in Windows Desktop. I dont made it abble to run on WP8. Or have a overlooked something?

Comment: You could in theory port it, but that's not my point. Check what's the difference from the code there to your code, and then you can see where you went wrong.

Comment: I've already tried this too. But there I also get not all messages from pebble. Do you own a WP8? Maybe you can try it? I can send you the ported code from your lib.

Comment: You tried to see what the difference was and tried to fix it? Also yeah I do, but I don't have a dev license yet.

Comment: I've tried to take your library, and changed the communication part. And there is my issue, dont know why. I'm going to play around with it, hopefully I get it fixed :)

Comment: get it fixed...it was the communication part.